# Run auto hot key script whenever I start PC

Tags: windows-7, automation, autohotkey

I compile the ahk script to make it a binary, then I copy the symbolic link to the startup directory so that ahk is run all the time when I start my PC.

The thing is that I see this warning sign all the time when PC starts.

[image]

- What's wrong with this?
- How to run AHK whenever I start PC? Does my method have some problem?

Comment: The message you are seeing ("An older instance of this script is already running") means you have started the script twice. This will go away when you solve your other question [why items your Startup folder seem to be running twice](http://superuser.com/questions/196677/run-programs-twice-in-startup-directory).

Comment: Have a look at 'msconfig > Startup' to see if it's entered twice.

Answer (score 1):

To make it stop giving you the message, add the following near the top of the script before you compile it:

```
#SingleInstance force
```

That will cause the newer version to replace the older version of the script.

*Please note*: this does not address the fact that you seem to have the script executing twice during your boot process.