# Run programs twice in startup directory?

Tags: windows-7, boot, autohotkey

I run the autoruns to see the following one.

[image]

The thing is that the user's startup files are registered twice. I'm not sure, but this might be the cause of the AHK problem that [I posted](https://superuser.com/questions/196663/run-auto-hot-key-script-whenever-i-start-pc), if the programs actually run twice if they are in startup directory.

What do you think? Is this a bug of autoruns program? Or, actually, Do the programs run twice?

### ADDED

With msconfig, I found that the runme.exe(the ahk script binary) is run twice. The weird thing is that when I deleted one of them, the runme.exe is removed from the startup directory.

Comment: Try opening that folder and see if there are two shortcuts in it.  If there are, have they got different properties?

Comment: @jason404 : I don't think so, as I just copied the link. When I copied the binary itself(not copy), I got the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Autoruns always does that: shows two entries that are linked to each other. I think it has something to do with the fact that there are two Startup locations:

`C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` vs

`C:\Documents and Settings\<your-name>\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`

Most programs have a feature (or option) of "don't start a second instance". Check if AHK has it.

Or my preferred way is to move most startups to 
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

(you know how to create a reg entry, right?) That doesn't have a "double startup" problem

Answer (score 0):

You can sere, what is started on Systemboot by typing msconfig into your commandline and hit enter. The Window you see in my screen is in german. The last tab is the one your looking for. There you can disable programs run at system start.

[image: msconfig]

If msconfig too shows you duplicate entrys, it is not a bug of Autoruns. If not, theres no problem ;-)

But, according to your other questinon, it might be the fact, that some programms are registered twice. As you can see in my screen, Adobe Reader for example is registered twice. That happens from time to time, although I don´t know yet why...

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that these two startup entries have different parameters?
Meaning that they are really distinct and not duplicated.